Как поменять раскладку arduino pro micro
При подключении к ПК arduino пишет команды в русской раскладке. Следуя инструкции отсюда, я пытался получить раскладку клавиатуры с помощью Serial.read() и поменять ее в том случае, если она русская в данный момент. Вот полный код:
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600);
   if (Serial.read() == '2') {
      Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ALT);
      Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
      delay(45);
      Keyboard.releaseAll();
      delay(100);
   };
   Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
   Keyboard.press('r');
   delay(45);
   Keyboard.releaseAll();
   delay(100);
   Keyboard.print("Test");
};
void loop(){
  
};

Но тут у меня вообще перестало что-либо происходить при подключении платы к пк. Как это можно исправить и при этом переключать раскладку на нужную?

А вы программу, описанную в конце статьи, у себя на ПК запустили?

Спасибо, что подсказали, я не дочитывал до конца, т. к. только искал способ переключить раскладку на нужную мне, поэтому не заметил программу. Есть ли способ переключать раскладку  без нее?

Клавиатура ничего не знает про раскладку. Ни про текущую, ни про способ переключения. Так что без какой-то вспомогательной утилиты на ПК никак.
